# Why is complex conjugation so slow?

Tags: python, numpy, performance

It's on par with complex multiplication, which boggles my mind:

```py
import numpy as np

def op0(x):
    return np.conj(x)
    
def op1(x0, x1):
    return x0 * x1
    
def op2(x0, x1):
    x0[:] = x1

for N in (50, 500, 5000):
    print(f"\nshape = ({N}, {N})")
    x0 = np.random.randn(N, N) + 1j*np.random.randn(N, N)
    x1 = np.random.randn(N, N) + 1j*np.random.randn(N, N)

    %timeit op0(x0)
    %timeit op1(x0, x1)
    %timeit op2(x0, x1)
```

```
shape = (50, 50)
3.55 µs ± 143 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
4.85 µs ± 261 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
1.85 µs ± 116 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

shape = (500, 500)
1.52 ms ± 60.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
1.96 ms ± 133 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
299 µs ± 50.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

shape = (5000, 5000)
163 ms ± 4.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
185 ms ± 11.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
39.8 ms ± 399 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Why is flipping the sign of `x.imag` so expensive? Surely, at low level, it's much easier than several multiplications and additions (`(a + j*b)*(c + j*d)`)?

Windows 10 x64, numpy 1.23.5, Python 3.10.4

Comment: I don't think complex conjugation actually takes much of that time. Remember, you're not just doing math. You're also doing memory allocation and memory access.

Comment: But memory access and allocation happens with anything. Upon its shared cost `c`, multiplication should add much more than conjugation, and multiplication should cost way more than access and allocation. Multiplication also has quadruple the access (two arrays, need real and imaginary), and double the allocation (need real). Added test case.

Comment: A useful additional reference point to @user2357112 's point would be to simply copy the input array to a freshly-allocated one.  Another point of comparison might be a sign-flip operation on real or complex data, or how the times are affected if you represent the real and imaginary parts separately and implement the conjugation yourself.

Comment: "Multiplication also has quadruple the access (two arrays, need real and imaginary), and double the allocation (need real)." - you're miscounting. First, complex conjugation still has to handle the real part, so the allocation is identical, and it's only double the read access. Second, you're neglecting the *write* access.

Comment: When I throw in a `%timeit x0.copy()`, it takes about as long as the `np.conj(x0)`.

Comment: @user2357112 My allocation counting was actually in regards to writing. How is it double the read? `conj` only needs to read the imaginary part of one array, multiplication has to read real and imaginary of two arrays.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon: The output has a real part. How are you going to populate that without reading the real part of the input?

Comment: @user2357112 Right, I was thinking in-place.

Comment: Compare it with `x0.real - 1j * x0.imag`

Comment: there was a recent SO about the time complexity of `x0.imag`. `complex` is 2d floats, so `imag` has to access every other value, a bit like `x[::2]` for a regular float.

Comment: For more fun, include `def op3(x): return -x` in the timings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer based on the many previous comments:

> Unsure if I should be impressed with how fast complex multiplication is or disappointed with how slow rudimentary array stuff is.

Memory accesses are slow and they will be slower in the future because of the memory-wall (which started >20 year ago). If you want something fast, you need to not use your DRAM. Numpy is not specifically designed for that (which is quite sad). Your hardware reach 17.2 GiB/s. This is not a lot but not very bad either. Modern PCs can reach 40-60 GiB/s (some, like the M1, can even reach >60 GiB). Modern intel CPU L3 cache can reach ~400 GiB/s, so a lot more.

GPUs often have a significantly higher memory throughput but the ratio `computational_speed` / `memory_bandwidth` is still high like on CPUs (even often higher actually). CPU have pretty big caches nowadays while GPUs often do not. Note that GPU computations can be delayed by some API (lazy computation) so you should care about that in benchmarks (you can print the value for example).

> op5 vs op6: extra 2*S reads, 4*S multiplies, 4*S adds don't even double compute time. So writes are the most expensive?

All operations should be memory bound here. Only memory operations matters.

`op5` is slower than `op6` because `op5` read two arrays while `op6` read one. More data needs to be transferred from the DRAM so it takes more time. Besides, write can be more expensive than read, but this is dependent of the compiled assembly code (so the compiler, the optimization flags and the actual source code) and the target architecture. Memory performance is a complex topic, much more than it seems (see below for more information about this).

Note that it does not matter that it's two separate arrays. 1 big array virtually split in two part would have the same impact. There is not much difference from the hardware.

---

### General notes

Regarding the timings, modern memory/CPUs are pretty complex so it is generally not easy to understand what is going on based on benchmark (especially without the assembly code). Writes and reads are almost equally fast from the DRAM perspective. Mixing them reduce performance because of the way DRAMs work. Modern x86-64 CPU caches use a write-allocate policy resulting in read being done when write are performed. This causes writes being 2 time slower than read. That being said, non-temporal instruction can be used to avoid this issue, assuming the compiler generate them

Compilers often do not generate non temporal instructions because they can be much slower when the array fit in the cache, and in this case, the compiler used to build Numpy cannot know the size of the arrays (runtime defined). It cannot know the size of the CPU cache either. Memory copies tends to use the `memcpy` basic function which is optimized to use non temporal instruction for large array regarding the target platform. AFAIK, such instruction are not used in Numpy for operations like multiplications/additions, etc. (at least not on my machine).

Note that I mention "modern CPUs" because pre-Zen AMD CPUs use a very different approach. Other CPU architectures like POWER also behave very differently in this case. Any detail matters when it comes to high performance. This is also why I said the topic is complex. The best is to do a low-level profiling on your specific machine or list your hardware, the exact Numpy package (or the assembly code used) in order to avoid considering many possible things that could theoretically happen.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how I missed this.

Answer (score 2):

Moving that to and from memory takes most of the time.

I came up with idea similar to Sarah Messer (in comments above). Just copying input array takes significant amount of time:

```
def op0(x):
    return np.conj(x)

def op3(x):
    return x.copy()
```

There is about 20% difference in timings between those operations.

###### in-place conjugation

As Jerome mentioned in the comment, using `out` parameter:

```
def op0B(x):
    np.conj(x, out=x)
```

is 3x faster on my machine for N=5000.

For small N improvement is negligible. Interestingly for N=500 speed-up is even better (5-6x).

Comment: If the OP is OK to use in-place operations, note that `np.conj` has an `out` parameter for that which should make things faster on most machine for large arrays.

Comment: @JérômeRichard good idea, if not OP, maybe someone in the future will benefit. Did update, performance is significantly better.

Answer (score 1):

Tested more fully, full results at bottom. Key results:

```
op4 = lambda x:      np.conj(x, out=x)
op5 = lambda x0, x1: np.multiply(x0, x1, out=x0)

def op6(x0, x1): 
    x0[:] = x1
```

Score

```
shape = (5000, 5000)
4: 43.5 ms ± 2.63 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
5: 71.7 ms ± 4.15 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
6: 43.3 ms ± 3.27 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

`operation(x, out=x)` in NumPy makes it in-place, correct me if wrong. Using `out=out` with a pre-allocated `out` is slower (see below). So... convinced, I guess.

Unsure if I should be impressed with how fast complex multiplication is or disappointed with how slow rudimentary array stuff is.

#### Operations breakdown

Let `S = N**2`:

- `op4`: `S` reads, `S` writes -- `S` sign flips
- `op5`: `4*S` reads, `2*S` writes -- `4*S` multiplies, `4*S` adds
- `op6`: `2*S` reads, `2*S` writes

`op4` vs `op6`: `S` reads, `S` writes are on par with `S` sign flips - seems fair.

`op5` vs `op6`: extra `2*S` reads, `4*S` multiplies, `4*S` adds don't even double compute time. So writes are the most expensive?

Let me know if my analysis is off.

#### Full results

```py
import numpy as np

op0 = lambda x:           np.conj(x)
op1 = lambda x0, x1:      x0 * x1
op2 = lambda x, out:      np.conj(x, out=out)
op3 = lambda x0, x1, out: np.multiply(x0, x1, out=out)
op4 = lambda x:           np.conj(x, out=x)
op5 = lambda x0, x1:      np.multiply(x0, x1, out=x0)

def op6(x0, x1):
    x0[:] = x1

for N in (50, 500, 5000):
    print(f"\nshape = ({N}, {N})")
    out = np.zeros((N, N), dtype='complex128')
    x0  = np.ones((N, N),  dtype='complex128')
    x1 = x0.copy()

    %timeit op0(x0)
    %timeit op1(x0, x1)
    %timeit op2(x0, out)
    %timeit op3(x0, x1, out)
    %timeit op4(x0)
    %timeit op5(x0, x1)
    %timeit op6(x0, x1)
```

```
shape = (50, 50)
0: 4.32 µs ± 160  ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
1: 4.81 µs ± 280  ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
2: 2.83 µs ± 28.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
3: 4.25 µs ± 293  ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
4: 2.69 µs ± 38.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
5: 3.98 µs ± 67.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
6: 1.78 µs ± 29.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

shape = (500, 500)
0: 1.43 ms ± 94.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
1: 1.48 ms ± 26.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
2: 401 µs  ± 32.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
3: 845 µs  ± 66.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
4: 252 µs  ± 11.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
5: 532 µs  ± 17.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
6: 224 µs  ± 15.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

shape = (5000, 5000)
0: 165 ms  ± 3.26 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
1: 190 ms  ± 2.82 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
2: 62.4 ms ± 2.52 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
3: 87.7 ms ± 3.41 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
4: 43.5 ms ± 2.63 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
5: 71.7 ms ± 4.15 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
6: 43.3 ms ± 3.27 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: "*Unsure if I should be impressed with how fast complex multiplication is or disappointed with how slow rudimentary array stuff is.*"  Memory accesses are slow and they will be slower in the future because of the *memory-wall* (which started >20 year ago). If you want something fast, you need to not use your DRAM. Numpy is not specifically designed for that (which is quite sad). Your hardware reach 17.2 GiB/s. This is not a lot but not very bad either. Modern PCs can reach 40-60 GiB/s (some, like the M1, can even reach >60 GiB). Modern intel CPU L3 cache can reach ~400 GiB/s, so a lot more.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Good to know, thanks. I notice that parallelization-heavy operations are obscenely faster on GPUs using PyTorch, sometimes by more than I would think is explainable by increased core count alone. I wonder if what you said plays a role.

Comment: If you're confident in this information I encourage you to submit it as an answer, it explains things more than mere comparisons can, especially with my results. Would be nice if you'd also comment on the op5 vs op6 result but I can open that separately.

Comment: GPUs often have a significantly higher memory throughput but the ratio `computational_peed / memory_bandwidth` is still high like on CPUs (even often higher actually). CPU have pretty big caches nowadays while GPUs often do not. Note that GPU computations can be delayed by some API (lazy computation) so you should care about that in benchmarks (you can print the value for example).

Comment: `op5` read two array while `op6` read on. More data needs to be transferred from the DRAM so it takes more time. Regarding the answer, I guess comments and current answer should be enough to understand what is going on (note that memory performance is a complex topic, much more than it seems).

Comment: Yes and I wrote that as double the reads, or does it matter that it's from two _separate_ arrays? My confusion is that doubled reads and heavy math didn't result in doubled speed, so am I right to conclude that writes (which are same for both ops) take the most time?

Comment: It does not matter that it's two separate arrays. 1 big array virtually split in two part would have the same impact. There is not much difference from the hardware.

Comment: Regarding the timings, modern memory/processors are pretty complex so it is generally not easy to understand what is going on based on benchmark (especially without the assembly code). Writes and reads are almost equally fast from the DRAM perspective. Mixing them reduce performance because of the way DRAMs work. Modern x86-64 CPU caches use a write-allocate policy resulting in read being done when write are performed. This causes writes being 2 time slower than read. That being said, non-temporal instruction can be used to avoid this issue, assuming the compiler generate them.

Comment: Compilers often do not generate non temporal instructions because they can be much slower when the array fit in the cache, and in this case, the compiler used to build Numpy cannot know the size of the arrays (runtime defined). It cannot know the size of the CPU cache either. Memory copies tends to use the `memcpy` basic function which is optimized to use non temporal instruction for large array regarding the target platform. AFAIK, such instruction are not used in Numpy for operations like multiplications/additions, etc. (at least not on my machine).

Comment: Note that I mention "modern CPUs" because pre-Zen AMD processors use a very different approach. Other CPU architectures like POWER also behave very differently in this case. Any detail matters when it comes to high performance ;) . This is also why I said the topic is complex. The best is to do a low-level profiling on your specific machine or list your hardware, the exact Numpy package (or the assembly code used) in order to avoid considering many possible things that could theoretically happen.

Comment: This is all great info, thanks. I'd upvote an answer that's a copy-paste dump of all these comments, prefaced with something like "OP's `op5` vs `op6` results are because ..." It'd sure be a shame if the comments got deleted somehow.

Comment: I wrote an answer packing all comments here as you wished. I will probably delete comments here later unless you want to keep them.